# Lua how to push variables from lua to C++

Tags: c++, lua, lua-c++-connection

Hi I am trying to push variables from Lua to a C function, how would I do that? I have generated a C++ object on Lua side but want to send a number to that the objects function. But I get: Error when loading script with following string:

```
player.lua:2: attempt to index a function value (local 'myPlayer')
```

**player.lua**

```
local myPlayer = Player.new(69) 
myPlayer.testing(myPlayer, 24069)
```

**player.cpp**

```
int player_test_pos(lua_State* L)
{
    player* myPlayer = l_CheckPlayer(L, 1);
    myPlayer->setPos({ 10, 0, 30 });
    int ok = lua_istable(L, 1);
    std::cout << ok << std::endl;
    ok = lua_isnumber(L, 2);
    std::cout << ok << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you write the binding between Lua and C++? Using some library?

Comment: I use the Lua C API but I´m open to use other libraries if they are easy to use / learn

Comment: Ah, you are doing the binding manually through the C API. Not a problem per se, but it is so easy to get it wrong. You are not giving enough information in your question to answer it. *I have generated a C++ object on Lua side*: how? Could you share some code? *I am trying to push variables from Lua to a C function*: you mean, how to pass parameters to a C function from Lua? That should be easy (read them on stack).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay so here is my player.lua skript:                                                                                            local myPlayer = Player.new(69)
myPlayer.testing(myPlayer, 24069)

Comment: and here is my c function:                                                                                                                                     int player_test_pos(lua_State* L)
{
    player* myPlayer = l_CheckPlayer(L, 1);
    myPlayer->setPos({ 10, 0, 30 });
    int ok = lua_istable(L, 1);
    std::cout << ok << std::endl;
    ok = lua_isnumber(L, 2);
    std::cout << ok << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: @beamlight: It might be clearer if you edit the question itself, instead of adding comments below the question. There's an "Edit" link right below your question

Comment: @MSalters yeah I will do that from now on, thanks for claryfing! I´m still new to stackoverflow so I appreciate it!

Comment: The bug is in `Player.new` and is unrelated to your question title. Instead of returning some *object* (a value with a *metatable*, either a `table` or a `userdata`), the constructor returns some `function` value. I said that it is easy to get things wrong with the C API. Please show the code of the `Player.new` function.